# Find the General Solution of the DE (With One given solution $y_1(x) = x^2$)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$y' = 4x + x^{-1}y - 3x^{-3}y^2$$

Now I thought this was homogeneous because we have a lot of $\frac yx$'s

But looking at the solution it says this:

Rearrange the terms $y' -\frac yx + 3\cfrac{y^2}{x^3}=4x$

Then with Potential solution
$y_1(x)=x^2$

Use Sub

$y(x) = x^2 + \frac 1Z$

Thus, $y' = 2x - \cfrac{Z'}{Z^2}$

$y^2 = x^4 + \cfrac {2x^2}{Z} + \cfrac{1}{Z^2} $

Where does this come from? Where does $\frac 1Z$ come from? How does $y^2 = x^4 + \cfrac {2x^2}{Z} + \cfrac{1}{Z^2} $?

Is this still homogeneous or is this an entirely different DE solving technique entirely?

Can someone please explain the methodology/thought process?

Comment: Riccati, not Ricatti (ricatti with one "c" and two "t" means "blackmail" in Italian)

Comment: Sorry I had corrected it in my answer but cant edit my comment @enzotib

Answer (score 1):

$$y' = 4x + x^{-1}y - 3x^{-3}y^2$$
This is [Riccati's differential equation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation)

A well known substitution when a solution is known is
$$y=y_1+\dfrac 1 {u}$$
The DE can also be transformed into a Bernoulli's DE that is more easy to integrate. Substitute:
$$y=y_1+u$$
Where $y_1$ is a known solution of the Riccati's DE.

---

Another way to integrate it $(v=y/x^2)$:
$$y' = 4x + x^{-1}y - 3x^{-3}y^2$$
$$\dfrac {y'}x = 4 +v - 3v^2$$
$$y=vx^2 \implies y'=x^2v'+2xv$$
$$xv'+2v= 4 +v - 3v^2$$
$$xv'= 4 -v - 3v^2$$
Is separable.